# How to install a language to a database when I create a database?

Tags: database, postgresql, language

I have two postgres database servers. Let's name that A and B respectively.

When I create a database in A, I don't have to run the following command to install a language.

```
createlang -U postgres plpgsql {database name}
```

Somehow...I have to run the above command in B.

How do I make it so that server B installs 'plpgsql' language when I create a database?

Comment: @ChrisS // You're totally right. I forgot to choose an answer for all my questions...bad bad...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the language onto the template databases.  The default template-database is named `template1`, and is the one copied when you create new databases.  Any modifications you make to this database, should appear on new databases.

Check out http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/manage-ag-templatedbs.html for more information.

Comment: Note, the above answer mostly applies to pre-9.0 versions of postgres; as of 9.0 plpgsql is installed by default.